# How do I insert a variable into an expected string, delimiting issue? Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to retrieve data from Yahoo Finance through the WEBSERVICE function and then populate the data through a loop. I know the issue is with the apostrophes, since there are two variables I am not sure how to delimit them. I've tried combinations of " & symbol & ", double apostrophes, nothing worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

The code is:

```
Sub marketdata()

    Dim symbol As String
    Dim parameter As String
    Dim rows As Long
    Dim cols As Long

    For rows = 2 To 5700
        For cols = 3 To 20
            symbol = Cells(rows, 2).Value
            parameter = Cells(1, cols).Value
            Cells(rows, cols).Value = "=WEBSERVICE _
            (""https://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=SYMBOL&f=PARAMETER"")"
        Next cols
    Next rows

End Sub
```

This is my first post, please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two Replace operations to put the cell values into the string.

```
Dim sp As String
Dim rows As Long
Dim cols As Long

For rows = 2 To 5700
    For cols = 3 To 20
        sp = "=WEBSERVICE(""https://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%1%&f=%2%"")"
        sp = Replace(Replace(sp, "%1%", Cells(rows, 2).Value), "%2%", Cells(1, cols).Value)
        Debug.Print sp
        Cells(rows, cols).Value = sp    'should this be .Formula?
    Next cols
Next rows
```

You might also wish to start including parent worksheet references.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfect! Formula and value both are evaluated as a formula here for me.

Comment: Yes, Excel will *usually* interpret a formula put into the .Value as a formula but that doesn't make it right; it simply means that your programming relies on the VBA 'overhead' to correct mistakes. Try it with a cell formatted as Text.